# Problem using nppToR or Tinn-R

Tags: r, tinn-r

Thanks everybody for the reply! Now I fixed the problem by R 2.12.1 and NpptoR (version 2.5.2), without setting the registry.

After a while of my updating of R from 2.11.1 to 2.12.0, I was now completely unable to pass scripts to R from Notepad++ (working together with nppToR).

when I installed nppToR, I always get the same dialogue of `"Could not find the Rgui.exe file. Aborting"`, and it will not ready for use. I thought it is caused by the updating of R.2.11.1 to R.2.12.0 because the Rgui.exe were located in different location. Then, for a while, the nppToR works after I edit the nppToR.ini file, from this:

```
[install]
global=1
```

into this, which is also from the previous version of the nppToR files:

```
[executables]
R=C:\Program Files\R\R-2.12.0\bin\i386\Rgui.exe  --max-mem-size=2047M
Rcmdparms=
Npp=
NppConfig=
[hotkeys]
passline=F8
passfile=^F8
evaltocursor=+F8
batchrun=^!F8
rhelp=^F1
[putty]
activateputty=1
puttyline=F9
puttyfile=^F9
[controls]
Rpastewait=50
Rrunwait=10
restoreclipboard=1
appendnewline=1
[silent]
enablesilent=1
silentkey=!F8
[install]
global=1
```

However, in these days, this modification never work for me, even though I uninstalled the R.2.12.0 and installed R.2.11.1. And I really have no idea the reason for that. Is there some one had the same experiences? Or, can some one help me out?

PS.: I also tried Tinn-R as an alternative, but after some time of use, the cursor usually appear in some position just like it is going mad, and when I input the code, each line can have only one single letter, and the cursor will move to the next line automatically.Do any body know why?

Thank in advance~

Best Regards~

Marco

Comment: Tinn-R just works fine for me with every version of R, and does so for 2+ years. I don't know what you did wrong, but the problem is definitely not Tinn-R. In any case, more info on your system is always useful.

Comment: I think I just cannot find the reason for the problem, as I installed both R(2.12.0) and Tinn-R(2.3.7.1) as default, and after some lines of scripts, the cursor will just stop somewhere of Tinn-R, while I can still input some letters directed by the cursor that I cannot see, and each letter will occupy one single line and jump to the next line automatically. However, as I prefer Rgui than Rterm, I would like to use Notepad++ over Tinn-R. Now with the help of Marek, I am able to use R.2.11.1 altogether with nppToR2.4.0, and I think I will have no problem right now! Thanks for the concern~

Comment: I always use Rgui with Tinn-R. I can't reproduce your problem, sorry. Glad you found something that worked.

Comment: This is a known problem that I am working on fixing.  Not entirely sure why it happens yet but I have been able to reproduce it at least.

Comment: I have used NPPtoR with no trouble in the past. Around beginning of 2011 I upgraded both and encounter the same error. I have not gone to much trouble to track down the cause(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you got [recent nppToR (currently <del>2.5.1</del> 2.5.2)](http://sourceforge.net/projects/npptor).

There are some problems but generally: R<=2.11.1 works with nppToR<=2.4.0 and R>=2.12.0 works with nppToR>=2.5.0. *(EDIT) <del>Not tested but I think that</del> 2.5.2 works with all versions.*
Also you have to set registry keys (no bother if you do standard R instalation) to R paths.

---

Yesterday I had similar problems and I come to working version by:

- install R (in my case 2.12.1), from installer with modified settings, but with `set registry keys` option.
- install NppToR (2.5.1)

Comment: Thanks Marek~  I fixed the problem with nppToR2.4.0 and R.2.11.1, and the registry is really matters.

Answer (score 2):

The registry is not necessary if the R home directory is specified in the settings, but the registry is simpler for people who do regular installs.

Right click on the NppToR icon and select settings then specify the R home directory.  There should never be a need to directly edit the ini file.

**Update**

The new version of NppToR, 2.5.2, tries to fix this exact problem.

Comment: With wrong settings in registry you cannot run NppToR at all :/

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your TinnR is properly configured. The directory structure has recently changed on the default R installation so your editor might be a bit lost.

Also TinnR hotkeys seam to be a bit bugging with the last R version (2.12.1), at least on the 64bits version

Comment: Thanks Fred~ Right now I am working on R 2.11.1 with Notepad++ and NpptoR(2.4.0) according to Marek's suggestion, and they just work fine~

Comment: You can try as well Eclipse, I have just discovered that there is a cool plugin for R. See http://www.splusbook.com/RIntro/R_Eclipse_StatET.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I tried to figure a way to let nppToR know where to find Rgui.exe and it works now. 
When you set up the path in the setting, you should not set the full path information. 
For my case, I just put "C:\Program Files\R\R-2.15.1" there. 
The program will automatically add "\bin\i386\Rgui.exe".

Hopefully it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. if you have windows 64 bit installed on your pc, you must install R in Program files (X86) instead of 64 bit default program files.